# Elixir PostgreSQL - select query returning results which do not conform to WHERE clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, elixir, ecto

I have this function which select shops and their products from my database:

```
def create_unique_shop_query_no_keyword(categories, shop_ids) do
    products_shops_categories = from p in Product,
    join: ps in ProductShop, on: p.id == ps.p_id,
    join: s in Shop, on: s.id == ps.s_id,
    join: pc in ProductCategory, on: p.id == pc.p_id,
    join: c in Subcategory, on: c.id == pc.c_id,
    distinct: s.id,
    where: c.id in ^categories,
    where: s.id in ^shop_ids,
    group_by: [s.id, s.name],
    select: %{products: fragment(
      "json_agg( DISTINCT (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)) AS products",
      p.id,
      p.name,
      p.brand,
      p.description,
      p.image,
      p.rating,
      p.number_of_votes,
      ps.not_in_shop_count,
      ps.is_in_shop_count,
      ps.price,
      p.not_vegan_count,
      p.vegan_count),
      shop: fragment(
        "json_agg( DISTINCT (?, ?, ST_X(?), ST_Y(?), ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)) AS shop",
        s.id,
        s.name,
        s.point,
        s.point,
        s.place_id,
        s.street,
        s.suburb,
        s.city,
        s.street_number
        )
      }
  end
```

I have another function that does the same thing, but with a keyword thrown into the mix, which checks for a keyword (not necessarily a full word) being in the product name, or the product brand:

```
def create_unique_shop_query(keyword, categories, shop_ids) do
    products_shops_categories = from p in Product,
    join: ps in ProductShop, on: p.id == ps.p_id,
    join: s in Shop, on: s.id == ps.s_id,
    join: pc in ProductCategory, on: p.id == pc.p_id,
    join: c in Subcategory, on: c.id == pc.c_id,
    distinct: s.id,
    where: c.id in ^categories,
    where: s.id in ^shop_ids,
    where: like(p.name, ^("%#{keyword}%")),
    or_where: like(p.brand, ^("%#{keyword}%")),
    group_by: [s.id, s.name],
    select: %{products: fragment(
      "json_agg( DISTINCT (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)) AS products",
      p.id,
      p.name,
      p.brand,
      p.description,
      p.image,
      p.rating,
      p.number_of_votes,
      ps.not_in_shop_count,
      ps.is_in_shop_count,
      ps.price,
      p.not_vegan_count,
      p.vegan_count),
      shop: fragment(
        "json_agg( DISTINCT (?, ?, ST_X(?), ST_Y(?), ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)) AS shop",
        s.id,
        s.name,
        s.point,
        s.point,
        s.place_id,
        s.street,
        s.suburb,
        s.city,
        s.street_number
        )
      }
  end
```

The top function, with no keyword, works as intended. But in the function which has a keyword, the results contain shops where the shop id (`s.id`) is not in `shop_ids`. Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an `or_where`, so your query condition is essentially....

`(c.id in categories) and (s.id in shop_ids) and (p.name like keyword) or (p.brand like keyword)`

As long as p.brand is like keyword, it will match.

This is probably what you're looking for, grouping the OR condition within the AND where for the keyword matching.

```
...
where: c.id in ^categories,
    where: s.id in ^shop_ids,
    where: like(p.name, ^("%#{keyword}%")) or like(p.brand, ^("%#{keyword}%")),
...
```

This translates it to

`(c.id in categories) and (s.id in shop_ids) and (p.name like keyword or p.brand like keyword)`